# Django: Add queryset to inlineformsets

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, inline-formset

I want to make a `queryset` on a field in an `inline formset`.. I have `Inovice` and `Product` models and `InvoiceDetails` model to link the `manytomany` relation between them.

here are the models:

```
class Invoices(models.Model):
    """The Invoice Creation Class."""    
    invoice_number = models.CharField(
        _('invoice_number'), max_length=100, unique=True, null=True)
    ....

class Products(models.Model):
    """Product Creation Class."""

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, default=1)
    barcode = models.CharField(_('barcode'), max_length=200, null=True)
    ....


class InvoiceDetail(models.Model):
        invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoices, related_name='parent_invoice')
        product = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='parent_product')
        quantity_sold = models.IntegerField(_('quantity_sold'))
        ...
```

when crearting an `invoice` i have inline formsets for the `products` which create an `invoice details` for every product.. now i want to filter the products that appear for the user to choose from them by the company. i searched a lot on how to override the queryset of inline formsets but found nothing useful for my case.

my forms:

```
class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoices
        fields = ('customer', 'invoice_due_date', 'discount', 'type')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.agent = kwargs.pop('agent')
        super(InvoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_customer(self):
      .....

    def clean(self):
      ......



class BaseDetailFormSet(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):

    def clean(self):
         ......


DetailFormset = inlineformset_factory(Invoices,
                                      InvoiceDetail,
                                      fields=('product', 'quantity_sold'),
                                      widgets= {'product': forms.Select(
                                        attrs={
                                            'class': 'search',
                                            'data-live-search': 'true'
                                        })},
                                      formset=BaseDetailFormSet,
                                      extra=1)
```

and use it in the views like that:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        invoice_form = InvoiceForm(
            request.POST, request.FILES, agent=request.user)
        detail_formset = DetailFormset(
            request.POST)
        .......
else:
    invoice_form = InvoiceForm(agent=request.user)
    detail_formset = DetailFormset()
```

so, how can it filter the products that show in `detail_formset` by company?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it be passing the user to **init** and loop on forms to override the queryset.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.agent = kwargs.pop('agent')
    super(BaseDetailFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for form in self.forms:
        form.fields['product'].queryset = Products.objects.filter(company=self.agent.company)
```

in views:

```
detail_formset = DetailFormset(agent=request.user)
```